# How do I interpret and make use of Github commit pages?

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit, git-commit

This is a really noob question. I found some code on Github and used part of it in my project and later I found a problem with that code and filed an issue on that project Github page and the maintainer fixed it and the issue now has a link to a "commit" page which looks something like this (from [this page](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/ced3d9158a7a8c676be504bb6cd3b5ffb7cc7f13) - that is not the real one, but good to illustrate the problem):

[image: What's going one here?]

and well, I guess that page contains the solution to my problem but I don't have a slightest idea of how to interpret it. There're lots of code highlighted with different colors and I just don't get what's going on.

How do I interpret such a commit page and make use of it?

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a newbie question the answer will omit the hardcore details which you see on that page such as "parent commit" and other things which are not important in most cases. So here we go...

That page doesn't show *some code*, instead it shows *how some code was changed*. Since you say the commit was referenced from the issue you filed you can assume that changes in this commit resolve the issue.

The commit page shows a set of changes - insertions, deletions and replacements (combination of insertion and deletion). Below is part of the image you provided with annotations:

[image]

On top is the name of the file. Each change happens in some file. File names are relative to project root. A commit can contain one or more changes and each will belong to some file and it will be displayed with this contextual information. Note that the change is displayed starting with line 2969 - this is done for brevity so that you don't need to scroll to the change. If you need to see what was around that code you can use the text expansion buttons. You can also use "View" button somewhere in the top right corner of the page region showing a specific file to see the entire file.

Note the pluses and minuses. Minuses mean some lines were removed and pluses mean some lines were added. There're three options here - additions only (when lines are inserted in some position of the text), deletions only (when some lines were deleted) and replacements which are combinations thereof.

On the image above you see a replacement. Line 2972 previously contained some code which was replaced with two lines of new code. So it's removal of one line and insertion of two lines. Note that although the line numbers match before the change - they go like "2969-2969", "2970-2970", etc, they no longer match after the change - now they go like "2973-2974", etc. This happened because replacing one line with two new lines moves the code below the change and all the line numbers after the change are offset by one.

The following image shows a separate insertion and a separate deletion:

[image]

Note that line 890 is aligned with line 896 because of other changes above which offset the text. If this change was the first one within the file those numbers would have match each other. First comes the insertion - the author decided to insert a new line with a variable declaration which is line 899 after the change. Then comes a deletion - the author decided to remove the line with a variable declaration from line 928 (number before the change). In this specific case the two changes happened in the same function and the author effectively moved the variable declaration from one place to another. Insertions are not necessarily accompanied by deletions and if they are then those are not necessarily relevant as here. The author might have found an unused variable and just removed the declaration - nothing would be inserted.

So this is what you see on the page.

What you should do depends on multiple factors.

If you were using the recommended Github flow (this is not absolutely necessary, so don't get upset immediately) and forked the project and edited the fork you could have "merged" the changes - this can often be done semi-automatically.

However your question hints that you just downloaded the code and edited it locally. If that's the case you have to locate relevant code in your project (using file names and function names near each change) and change your copy of the code appropriately.