# How can I find the code which caused the Heartbleed Bug before the fix was made?

Tags: openssl, heartbleed-bug

I can find the open source code for t1_lib.c, but is there a place where old code is stored? I need to do a project where I demonstrate to the class what can happen if this bounds check is not done, but I am not sure how much was added to the file to solve the problem. 
I am taking an advanced data security class, and this is the project I was assigned. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/731f431497f463f3a2a97236fe0187b11c44aead) is the Github commit that fixes the bug. It shows both "before" and "after" states of the code.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25035244/57428) explains how to interpret Github commit pages in case you're not familiar with that.